# Selenium stuck with Firefox

Tags: java, selenium

It appears that using firefox 45+ stalls in Selenium from time to time due to downloading of the from the following  https://aus5.mozilla.org/update/3/GMP/45.4.0/20160905130425/Linux_x86_64-gcc3/en-US/esr/Linux%204.4.0-34-generic%20(GTK%203.18.9%2Clibpulse%208.0.0)/default/default/update.xml. Is there a way to stop firefox from downloading this document and any addons? It seems that setting preferences does not work. I am using Selenium 3 beta 4

I set the following preferences but nothing is working:

```
    profile.setPreference("app.update.enabled",enabled)
    profile.setPreference("app.update.staging.enabled",enabled)
    profile.setPreference("app.update.auto",enabled)
    profile.setPreference("app.update.checkInstallTime",enabled)
    profile.setPreference("app.update.silent",!enabled)
    profile.setPreference("extensions.update.enabled",enabled)

    if(!enabled){
      profile.setPreference("app.update.interval",Int.MaxValue)
      profile.setPreference("app.update.checkInstallTime.days",Int.MaxValue)
      profile.setPreference("extensions.update.interval",Int.MaxValue)
      profile.setPreference("app.update.lastUpdateTime.xpi-signature-verification",Int.MaxValue)
      profile.setPreference("app.update.lastUpdateTime.search-engine-update-timer",Int.MaxValue)
      profile.setPreference("app.update.lastUpdateTime.experiments-update-timer",Int.MaxValue)
    }

profile.setPreference("media.gmp-gmpopenh264.enabled",enabled)
profile.setPreference("media.gmp-provider.enabled",false)
profile.setPreference("media.gmp-manager.lastCheck",Int.MaxValue)
profile.setPreference("media.gmp-gmpopenh264.lastUpdate",Int.MaxValue)
```

The preferences appear to be set in about:config but I still see the following which is where my tool freezes after a few dozen to 1000 tests. Due to the need for rotating proxies and many concurrent tests with 2 boxes, grid is out of the question.

```
1475863716583   addons.productaddons    INFO    sending request to: https://aus5.mozilla.org/update/3/GMP/45.4.0/20160905130425/Linux_x86_64-gcc3/en-US/esr/Linux%204.4.0-34-generic%20(GTK%203.18.9%2Clibpulse%208.0.0)/default/default/update.xml
1475863716756   addons.productaddons    INFO    Completed downloading document
1475863717793   addons.productaddons    INFO    sending request to: https://aus5.mozilla.org/update/3/GMP/45.4.0/20160905130425/Linux_x86_64-gcc3/en-US/esr/Linux%204.4.0-34-generic%20(GTK%203.18.9%2Clibpulse%208.0.0)/default/default/update.xml
1475863717914   addons.productaddons    INFO    Completed downloading document
```

Comment: I suspect my issue is the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789893